# Why is Microsoft Oauth2 API changing the scope of authorization requests?

Tags: oauth, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi, azure-api-apps

I'm creating an application which needs to request user authorization from a Microsoft Work account. And stumbled into this twice.

At first, I just wanted to read the user e-mail, so I requested the following scopes:

- User.Read
- Mail.Read
- Mail.ReadWrite
- Mail.ReadWrite.Shared
- Mail.Read.Shared

However, I kept getting "scope has changed" errors, and noticed that the authorized response from microsoft was automatically including the **Mail.Send** scope to the requests, even if I didn't request it and it was not present on the authorization web page.

My users don't care about that extra auth, so I just added **Mail.Send** to my request and moved on. Fine.

I am now required to include the **offline_access** to the scope list, so I can get Refresh Tokens and keep the app running in background. But when I do it, Microsoft replies me with an authorization request missing the 'offline_access' grant, even if the authorization page showed "**Access your data offline**" and no errors occur during authentication, yet my Oauth2 flow is broken with a "scope has changed" error:

```
Scope has changed from "mail.readwrite mail.read.shared mail.read    
mail.readwrite.shared mail.send offline_access user.read" to "mail.readwrite 
mail.read.shared mail.read mail.readwrite.shared mail.send user.read"
```

So is this a bug in Microsoft Oauth flow, or am I doing anything wrong?

**EDIT**: I reviewed the application permissions on https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/ and the '**offline_access**' scope is not listed there, or any other scope seemingly related. Maybe this means Graph does not yet support that scope, despite it being heavily documented?

Comment: The `offline_access` scope is listed. I can confirm this.

Comment: I'm seeing this too.  I tried using the "profile" scope, and that gets returned as a URI.  So the answer seems to be to use the full URIs Google uses corresponding to the OpenID Connect standard profile names.  As noted below, the issue seems to be in oauthlib rather than Google per se, and that behaviour can be overridden if needed.  (Oops, OP is about Microsoft -  there's also a similar question about Google; but I think the thrust of the comment remains valid.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this issue annoying as well. Read on if you are using Python & oauthlib to process the authentication request -

In Python 3 and requests_oauthlib library this generates a `Warning`, rather than an `Exception`. If you see the source code then you will find these lines in `oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/parameters.py`:

```
if not os.environ.get('OAUTHLIB_RELAX_TOKEN_SCOPE', None):
    w = Warning(message)
    w.token = params
    w.old_scope = params.old_scopes
    w.new_scope = params.scopes
    raise w
```

So all you have to do is set the `OAUTHLIB_RELAX_TOKEN_SCOPE` variable to `True` in your environment, to ignore this warning.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import os

os.environ['OAUTHLIB_RELAX_TOKEN_SCOPE'] = '1'
```

The code snippet above will most likely solve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

There is file  `/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/parameters.py`.

[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRCow.png)]

As you can see in the image there is an environment variable "OAUTHLIB_RELAX_TOKEN_SCOPE". Just add this to your environment with value 'True' or 1.