# Either 403 or Scope has changed error in google classroom, what do I do?

Tags: python, google-classroom

I am trying to get grades from a class's assignments but if I try to call the `service.courses().courseWork().list(courseId=course['id']).execute()` it gives me

```
Warning: Scope has changed from "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.me.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.rosters.readonly" to "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.student-submissions.me.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.rosters.readonly".
```

and if I change the scopes to the recommended ones, I get this.

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses/[id]/courseWork?alt=json returned "The caller does not have permission". Details: "The caller does not have permission">
```

my code:

```
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

import warnings

# Set up the OAuth2 flow
flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
    'client_secret.json',
    scopes=[
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.me.readonly",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.rosters.readonly",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses.readonly"
    ])


flow.run_local_server(port=0)

# Get the OAuth2 credentials
creds = flow.credentials

# You can then use the credentials to authenticate requests to the Google API
service = build('classroom', 'v1', credentials=creds)


# Get a list of all the courses that you are a part of
courses = service.courses().list().execute()

# Loop through the courses and print the course names and IDs
for course in courses['courses']:
    print(f"Course Name: {course['name']}")
    print(f"Course ID: {course['id']}")

    cw = service.courses().courseWork().list(courseId=course['id']).execute()
    
    for assig in cw['courseWork']:
        print(assig)
```

Comment: "but if I try to call the service.courses().courseWork().list(courseId=course['id']).execute()" - exactly what do you expect this line of code to mean? What do you think should happen, **step by step**, when it runs? **How many steps** do you think are involved? Did you try to check, one by one, **what happens** at **each step**? **Where exactly** does it seem to do something wrong? What should happen in that step instead, and why? Please read [mre] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue and I would encourage you to upvote or comment on the corresponding Google IssueTracker ticket https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/78592659.

In the OAuth protocol, servers [don't need to return the exact scopes requested](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.3). This is the case here as well as in other (non-Google) APIs. The server is returning the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.student-submissions.me.readonly` scope because it is equivalent to the the client-requested `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.me.readonly` scope.

However, a dependency in the Python client library (oauthlib) is treating this scope difference as an error instead of a warning.

If it's acceptable, one solution is to set the `OAUTHLIB_RELAX_TOKEN_SCOPE` variable to `True` in your environment to suppress the error, as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41810377/why-is-microsoft-oauth2-api-changing-the-scope-of-authorization-requests).

My guess for the reason you are getting a 403 when you change the client-requested scope is that you may not have updated the [scopes in your GCP project](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/appsmarket-component.googleapis.com/googleapps_sdk)when you changed them in your code.

Comment: I actually commented out the check params for the scope (the function that was causing the scope change warning) but I got 403. I was unable to update the question at the time, however. The last paragraph should answer my question, thanks so much!

Comment: It actually didn't work, but it turned out I was missing the `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.student-submissions.students.readonly"` scope also.